# for each line, list the sum of sales together with the average of thoses who sold more

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm trying to answer this question:
"For each salesman, list his/her sales together with the average sales for those salesman who sold more than he/she did.

```
select sum(p.price * d.qty)
from salesman s 
join invoices i on (i.salesman = s.salesman)
join detail d on (d.ino = i.ino)
join parts p on (p.pno = d.pno)
where ---------(
  select sum(p.price * d.qty)
  from salesman s 
  join invoices i on (i.salesman = s.salesman)
  join detail d on (d.ino = i.ino)
  join parts p on (p.pno = d.pno)
)
group by s.salesman
order by s.salesman
```

i dont know how to compare every other sales with the one i got from the current row, and repeat that for every salesman

salesman is linked by some tables to reach the cost and the quantity sold of the parts

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with the sales for each sales person:

```
select i.salesman, sum(p.price * d.qty)
from invoices i join
     detail d
     on d.ino = i.ino join
     parts p
     on p.pno = d.pno
 group by i.salesmane;
```

Then, you can get your average using window functions:

```
select i.salesman,
       sum(p.price * d.qty),
       avg(sum(p.price * d.qty)) over (order by sum(p.price * d.qty) rows between 1 following and unbounded following)
from invoices i join
     detail d
     on d.ino = i.ino join
     parts p
     on p.pno = d.pno
group by i.salesmane;
```

Comment: i dont know the key words "over" and "rows between 1 following and unbounded following"

Comment: @TommyRoy . . . These are what Oracle calls analytic functions.  You can look them up in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

try creating a temporary table #TempSales with the total sales for each saleman
the # will create a temporary table in the tempdb database and will be dropped when the users session is closed if you do not drop it yourself
you can run the entire query below in one transaction.

{
    select s.salesman,sum(p.price * d.qty) as TotalSales
    into #TempSales
    from salesman s 
    join invoices i on (i.salesman = s.salesman)
    join detail d on (d.ino = i.ino)
    join parts p on (p.pno = d.pno)
    group by s.saleman

```
select s.Salesman,TotalSales,(select avg(TotalSales) from #TempSales t where t.salesman <> s.salesman and t.TotalSales > s.TotalSales) as AverageSales
from #TempSales
order by s.salesman
drop table #TempSales
```

}

Comment: i see where you are going for there, looks easier to understand